# Making wampserver MySQL public

Tags: mysql, localhost, wamp, wampserver

So I have applications in both Python and VB.net and they work fantastic, but I want to release them to the public.

I'm using my IP address for MySQL and nothing else w/ WAMPSERVER. They are both client desktop applications so I can't simply put up a website and connect that to a website.

How would I make the MySQL public, so that anyone including me can connect? [I've portforwarded port 3306 already]

Comment: How do you conx to the internet? Do you have a dedicated IP or do you get a different IP every time you conx?

Comment: I have a dedicated server that wampserver runs on.

Comment: Yep, and it connects to the internet somehow. Does it have it's own DNS record with an always-on connection or is this a machine behind your firewall in your home or work? The same question applies - does it always have the same IP or does the IP change when you disconx and reconx to the internet?

Comment: It always has the same IP. [and it's on my home network]

Comment: OK, is that IP something like 192.168.x.y? Cause I'm talking about the external IP. I'm talking about the IP address that someone from OUTSIDE would use to "see" your modem/router. Anyway, this is too hard to explain - if you do, in fact, have a dedicated IP address with a DNS record then you can just punch a hole in your firewall. If you don't then you will want dynamic dns.  Good luck!

Comment: I know the external IP and it always stays the same IP, but just unblocking port 3306 on the firewall on portforwarding didn't work, which I stated in the question.

Comment: If you are using windows, then you can add exception in the firewall for mysql as application.

Comment: I cannot say I think this is a good idea but, have you set the MySQL user account up so that it allows connections from any ip address. **I hope you are not using the `root` user account for this!!!**